# Bending moments when lifting houses

Tags: moment

I have a 3km-wide square with a tower in each corner (A,B,C,D). On edges AB and CD there are level rigid massless beams supported by the towers. A third beam lies on these two, parallel to BC (i.e. perpendicular to the first two). From somewhere on the third beam we have hung a house of mass 30 tonnes.

It is claimed that each tower

> will be under a minimum bending moment of ~$4.5 \times 10^8 \text{N}$.

([Source](http://asciiheart.tumblr.com/post/81481220803))

I'm trying to verify this claim. So my questions are:

1. Are the units correct?
2. Does the number make sense? (Under my assumptions, will the moment even be non-zero?)
3. If not, where might the number have come from?

Unless I've misunderstood something, bending moments are a subset of the moments that I learned about at school. This would mean that they would be measured in Nm, not N.

I can get approximately the right number ([calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30%20tonnes%20*%203km%20*%20g%20%2F%202&a=UnitClash_*g.*StandardAccelerationOfGravity--&a=UnitClash_*tonnes.*MetricTons.dflt--)), but even assuming that I've understood what a bending moment is, I think that there are some issues with this calculation (most notably that it seems to apply to one of the beams rather than to the towers).

Original scenario:

> Imagine the city is divided into a grid of squares 3 and a quarter kilometers on a side. All the grid points have tall narrow posts rising up from the ground, thoroughly anchored in the rock below. All the north-south lines of the grid have strong cables, like the cables this Earth uses to hold up suspension bridges, stretched between each grid point. (The cables are painted blue-reflective so that they mostly fade out against the sky, likewise the tower-posts.) Between two north-south cables, you can stretch east-west cables, side-by-side, attached by movable motors to points along the north-south cables, so the east-west cables can slide along the north-south cables. From points on the east-west cables, you can drop down nine vertical cables, again attached by motors so the vertical cables can slide along the east-west cables. The nine vertical cables pick up a house from its modular foundations, draw it upward, and then the vertical cables and east-west cables slide to convey the house to a grid point.

([Source](http://yudkowsky.tumblr.com/post/81447230971/my-april-fools-day-confession))

Comment: Bending moment should have units of Nm (Newton-meter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you need to go back and reread the source. The towers are not connected by rigid beams, but by cables. And in fact, if you use rigid beams instead of cables there is zero bending moment on the towers - all of the load is compressive.

But let's assume the post meant the bending moment on the beams, not the towers. You can go here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scas093/scas093.pdf for a tutorial on how to calculate the bending moment on a supported beam, or go here http://bendingmomentdiagram.com/solve/ for a calculator to play around with numbers. From this you can see that the maximum bending moment occurs when the load is suspended from the center of the beam. So the post you're having trouble with has got it exactly backwards - the *maximum* bending moment on a 3 km beam is what is calculated. Oh yes, and the assumed load is 60 tons, not 30.

Where the referenced bit of fantasy really goes wrong is when it assumes such a tower/cable system can do what the writer so blithely thinks it can. Consider a weight w suspended by 2 cables from two towers, as in

[image]

Just to make life easy, let's suspend the weight from equal length cables, so
$$T = T_1 = T_2$$ and
$$\theta = {\theta}_1 = {\theta}_2$$

Then $$T = \frac{w}{2 sin(\theta)}$$

Assume, just for the moment, that a tower is 50 meters tall, and it lifts a house 10 meters off the ground. Then, assuming no cable sag, $$\theta = \arcsin{\frac{40}{1500}} = 1.5 degree$$
and $T = 1125 tons$

For such a small angle, virtually all the force is directed in the horizontal plane, so we have the image of a "slender" tower resisting more than a thousand tons pulling sideways on its top.

Of course, you can always make the tower shorter and stubbier to resist the sideways pull, right? Ehrm, no.

Let's say you make the tower 20 meters high, and still lift the house 10 meters. Now$$\theta = \arcsin{\frac{10}{1500}} = .38 degree$$ and $T = 4523 tons$

Trying to suspend a heavy weight from a cable with little or no vertical deflection of the cable is a great way to snap the cable, since the tension goes as the inverse of the sine of the deflection. I saw a guy lose the end of his finger doing that.